# Trouble getting `contextType` property to work for React Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm having trouble getting the React `contextType` property that is part of the new React Context API. The documents say:

> The contextType property on a class can be assigned a Context object created by React.createContext(). This lets you consume the nearest current value of that Context type using this.context. You can reference this in any of the lifecycle methods including the render function.

Unless I've missed something, then, the following code should make `this.context` available on the `App` class:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const MyContext = React.createContext({
  on: false
});

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("context: ", this.context);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
App.contextType = MyContext;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

(Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n79m27qp70))

However, when this code runs, the log statement just prints an empty object. I expected it to print out the default state I provided to the `React.createContext` function.

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [React `>=16.6.0`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1660-october-23-2018) for this feature.
I updated react in your codesandbox and it works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/w66k2k8o5l

Comment: I am on react `16.8.6` but I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Reading around, the problem can also happen when there are circular dependencies. But this is not the case for me.